# is animate*AsState animating in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get is `animate*AsState` is currently animating. But how? Example of this:

```kotlin
val shape = animateIntAsState(
        if (!isSelected) 50 else 20,
        animationSpec = TweenSpec(150, 0)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a condition. `if (shape != 20 && shape != 50) return true else return false`

Answer (score 0):

For the `animate*AsState` functions, you would usually want to drive them using a boolean state variable. The animation itself can only be toggled between just two distinct values. You could rewrite your example as follows.

```
var isSelected by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

val shape = animateIntAsState(
        if (!isSelected) 50 else 20,
        animationSpec = TweenSpec(150, 0)
)
```

You can then toggle the animation by changing the value of `isSelected` in response to either an event call such as `onClick` or a `Side Effect` call.